# Renew Token before 2 min expire time spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler, timertask

Am working on a spring boot application having token authentication.
Have a scenario
**renew the token 2 minute before the expire time.**

which one is better for above scenario

1. Timer Task
2. Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You wont need a TimerTask or Scheduler if you just regenerate Token if it is expired.
Try this in Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = APIs.AUTHENTICATION_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) throws Exception
    {
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByPhoneNumber(request.getPhoneNumber());
    try
    {
        if (Utility.isBlankOrNull(employee.getJwtToken())
                    || jwtTokenUtil.isTokenExpired(employee.getJwtToken()))
                {
                    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(employee.getPhoneNumber());

                    employee.setJwtToken(token);
                    employeeRepository.save(employee);
                }
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e)
                {
                    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(employee.getPhoneNumber());

                    employee.setJwtToken(token);
                    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

as per your requirement

Every time your controller is called,you can calculate the time difference between token generation time and current time, if the difference if <= 2 minutes regenerate token.

If you are fetching token from a repository like in above code you can also write triggers to perform such operation.

Comment: my requirement is to renew before expire the token.

Comment: you cannot use TimerTask or Scheduler because it will only execute when your controller is called. After than it doesn't exist.